# from java know that ip on remote is connected

Tags: java

I have a desktop application in java, which only I should install, but other users are installing it, there is some way to know who installs the application is me, I had thought (but I find nothing about it) in that when the application is installed, see that ips are connected at that moment to the pc.

Would that be possible? Is there any better way to do it?

thank you.

Comment: It's unclear what are you asking 
I voted to close this question because it's so broad

Comment: You want to check if there's an application running on the whole network?

Comment: I will try to be as specific as I can, but understand that I do not know much English and I use the Google translator,
I have a desktop application in java, what I want to do is know who installs my application, is there any way to collect netstat data and save it in a log when it is installed?